# DISTINCT keyword gets removed from the query

Tags: java, jpa, distinct, datanucleus

Does any one have a clue why DISTINCT keyword is removed from the query when using DataNucleus (that's the software the company I work for uses)? I was able to debug the code and verified that the keyword is actually with the query. But by the time this function is called within JPAEntityManager

```
createQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery)
```

the DISTINCT keyword is removed. Debugging showed me it has something to do with

```
criteria.getCompilation(ec.getMetaDataManager(), ec.getClassLoaderResolver());
```

function call. Somehow createQuery() function works fine with SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DN_THIS) but not with SELECT DISTINCT FROM.

I hope some of you have at least a slight idea where the problem is since I'm fairly new with JPA and SQL queries in general that I can't find a quick solution on my own.

The query I'm trying to perform is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DN_THIS FROM Hop DN_THIS JOIN DN_THIS.tags t WHERE ((DN_THIS.entityStatus <> 'DELETED') AND ((t.name = :DN_PARAM_4) OR (t.name = :DN_PARAM_5))) ORDER BY DN_THIS.name ASC
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your SQL query to the question.

Comment: why not define the Criteria code you use?, and then post what is the toString() of the criteriaQuery ? and what is in the log when you execute it

Comment: @NeilStockton This is the log after executing `createQuery` and running the web app: 2014-08-28 10:27:46 INFO  Query:77 - Reading in results for query "SELECT FROM com.liaison.service.core.edm.model.Script DN_THIS JOIN DN_THIS.tags t WHERE (((((DN_THIS.type = :DN_PARAM_29) OR (DN_THIS.type = :DN_PARAM_30)) OR (DN_THIS.type = :DN_PARAM_31)) OR (DN_THIS.type = :DN_PARAM_32)) AND ((DN_THIS.entityStatus <> 'DELETED') AND ((t.name = :DN_PARAM_27) OR (t.name = :DN_PARAM_28)))) ORDER BY DN_THIS.name DESC". The query is defined dynamically instead of hard-coded strings.

Answer (score 0):

I prompted a developer of DataNucleus, who seems to have already [fixed the use of DISTINCT in criteria](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCJPA-281) which was simply not being passed across to the generated query.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. It seems we have version 3.2.5 in use of DataNucleus JPA API, and the current version of JPA API is 4.0.2. That makes sense, for me, if the DISTINCT issue is already fixed in Criteria.